# error while trying to install detectron2: error: metadata-generation-failed × Encountered error while generating package metadata

Tags: python, installation, deep-learning, detectron

I am trying to install detectron2 using Pip but I face this error:

```
MacBook-Air desktop % python -m pip install -e detectron2
Obtaining file:///Users/test/Desktop/detectron2
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [14 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/Users/test/Desktop/detectron2/setup.py", line 10, in <module>
          import torch
        File "/Users/test/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 201, in <module>
          _load_global_deps()
        File "/Users/test/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 154, in _load_global_deps
          ctypes.CDLL(lib_path, mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
        File "/Users/test/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 381, in __init__
          self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
      OSError: dlopen(/Users/test/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_global_deps.dylib, 0x000A): Library not loaded: '@rpath/libmkl_intel_thread.dylib'
        Referenced from: '/Users/test/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_global_deps.dylib'
        Reason: tried: '/Users/test/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libmkl_intel_thread.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/test/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/../../../../libmkl_intel_thread.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/test/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libmkl_intel_thread.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/test/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/../../../../libmkl_intel_thread.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/test/opt/anaconda3/lib/libmkl_intel_thread.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/test/opt/anaconda3/lib/libmkl_intel_thread.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/test/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/../../libmkl_intel_thread.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/test/opt/anaconda3/lib/libmkl_intel_thread.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/test/opt/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libmkl_intel_thread.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libmkl_intel_thread.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libmkl_intel_thread.dylib' (no such file)
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```